# arduino not loading library

Tags: library

I am receiving a compilation error from

```
#include <HX711.h>
```

The error is

```
fatal error: HX711.h: No such file or directory
```

However, C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\HX711 is there and has the correct files in it. 
Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage libraries says that HX711 is installed. Strange thing is that I have another sketch that uses this library and it compiles. It uses quotes instead of angle brackets (which is strange because HX711.h is not in the same directory) and it works.
I have tried both quotes and angle brackets.

EDIT: I am really sorry about typing "define" instead of "include" into the question my only excuse was that it was late.
I copied the library directory to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries
```

and the problem remains.

I now have the HX711 directory in both the Arduino program files and the user directories and it still complains about it. The only way I can get it to compile is to place the hx711.h & hx711.cpp files directly into the sketch directory and change the line to #include "HX711.h"

EDIT:
Running Arduino 1.6.5 on Windows 8.1 64bit

Comment: What platform are you using? (Windows. iOS, Linux)  What IDE version are you using?

Comment: @Matt Running Arduino 1.6.5 on Windows 8.1 64bit

Answer (score 2):

You're using `#define` when it should be `#include`.

Comment: I never saw that :D

Comment: you can mark my answer as the solution then :)

Comment: I thought the op had to do that.

Comment: Very sorry @H.Woszczyk that was just a silly typo. The problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Is the line of code really

```
#define &lt;HX711.h>
```

If it is then replace `&lt;` with `<` and that will fix it.

If the include statement has angle brackets <> around it then the file should be located in the system library folder, `C:\Program Files\Arduino\Libraries` on Windows.  I think there can now be a user library folder as well `C:\Users\PHemans\Documents\Arduino\Libraries` and I *think* that the <> include will pick up from here too.

If the file is in you local folder (same place as the ino) then you should use "" the file name.

It is also possible that what you are seeing is not what the compiler is seeing, so deleting the whole line and then retyping it can sometimes work, as can checking the file endings and encodings using a tool like Notepad++.

Comment: I did what you suggested @Matt I now have the HX711 directory in both the Arduino program files and the user directories and it still complains about it. The only way I can get it to compile is to place the hx711.h & hx711.cpp files into the sketch directory and change the line to #include "HX711.h"

Comment: Installing libraries to the IDE installation folder(C:\Program Files\Arduino\Libraries in your example) is a bad idea because all the libraries you install there will be lost when you update to a new IDE version. Always install the libraries to the {sketchbook}/libraries folder.